# if username exists how to suggest new username in android studio and tried one example but unable to manage it

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I want username suggestion like this [this is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjtGi.jpg)

if username already exists in database i want to show username suggestion with firstname with random number in the list.it will be helpful for me if any gave any example thanks in advance

Here is my code I have generated the 3 random number arraylist and how to display that three random number with firstname in a list on edittext for username suggestion if user already exists in Database. thanks in advance

```
    public class Randomgenerator extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText fname;
    EditText username;
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_random);

        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.random);

        fname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.random2);
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1); 

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int x = rand.nextInt(500)+1;
            final String s = String.valueOf(x);
            String string1 = null;
            for (int i=0;i<3;i++){
                string1=fname.getText().toString().concat(s);
                username.setText(string1);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Username Exists? But where ? Explain the concept.

Comment: in server database, it is for registration form

Comment: If you are talking about last logins user names for your app . Then just save them in a Persistence Data storage in Database or in SharedPreference . And then show an [AutoCompleteTextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html) to show suggestion .

Comment: no, it is for new user registration, if user already exist with the same name in db, i just want to display a username suggestion with new username like the image given above

Comment: I think this will be appear as a vulnerability to your app . Cause ultimately you will expose the other user's user name, isn't it ? Anyway If thats what you want to do then just set a `TextWatcher` on `edittext` and ask server for suggestion  and show them  as list .

Comment: Or if i get it wrong and you want to show the user the available userNames like Skype or Gmail. Then simply follow the approach  provided above . Thx

Comment: yes i want to show the username suggestion like gmail

Comment: Follow the approach i have provided above .Your server should should return the available usernames shich starts with the given `String`. Good luck'

Comment: which approch textwatcher on edittext

Comment: Yeah. If you don't know how it works there are plenty of tuts available . just Search for it and you are good to go .

Comment: is it possible to generate username suggestion from android side not from the server side

Comment: NO . How could you will know if some username is already in use unless you have all the registered User names in local database.

Comment: my server side database shows that username already exists in response, when i registered with the same username, if i get this response else part how do i code to suggest username

Comment: LOL . Think! will this work in anyway . You suggested a name then your server says its  already exists.Then why did you suggested it at first place if its  already exists? You should suggest only those names which are available thats it . No more discussion . Good luck

Comment: Please change your Server response, when Server detect that username already exists then server should give response consist of two things: ErrorMessage and List of suggested user names. It will save round trip to server and Database.